# Strategy to solve the Missionaries and Cannibals problem

Tags: strategy, river-crossing

In the [Missionaries and Cannibals problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionaries_and_cannibals_problem#The_problem):

> Three missionaries and three cannibals must cross a river using a boat which can carry at most two people, under the constraint that, for both banks and the boat, if there are missionaries present on the bank (or the boat), they cannot be outnumbered by cannibals (if they were, the cannibals would eat the missionaries). The boat cannot cross the river by itself with no people on board.

[The shortest solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missionaries_and_cannibals_problem#Solution) for this puzzle has 11 one-way trips.

**What should be the strategy to solve this puzzle for M missionaries and C cannibals**, given that M is not less than C, or else the puzzle wouldn't be solvable.

Comment: Is it even possible to do with more than three of each? I've never heard a solution to the problem for four missionaries and four cannibals.

Comment: There is a good discussion of a tree approach in the Wikipedia article you link to.  The first reference is to an article that probably answers the question very nicely, but it is behind a paywall.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's define `a b * c d` to represent the state of the river at any given time: `a` missionaries and `b` cannibals on the left, `c` missionaries and `d` cannibals on the right, and `*` being `<` if the boat is on the left and `>` if the boat is on the right.

The problem starts out in the state `M C < 0 0`, and we want to get `0 0 > M C`.

For the case of `M` being more than `C`, here's an algorithm to transfer 1 missionary and 1 cannibal at a time:

- Bring 1 missionary and 1 cannibal over. (`M-1 C-1 > 1 1`)
- Bring the *cannibal* back. (`M-1 C < 1 0`; since `M > C`, `M-1 >= C`, as required.)
- Bring 1 missionary and 1 cannibal over again. (`M-2 C-1 > 2 1`)
- Bring a missionary back. (`M-1 C-1 < 1 1`).

And then you're left with the case of `M-1` missionaries and `C-1` cannibals on one side of the river. Just keep repeating this procedure (it works by induction) until you have only missionaries on the left side of the river. Then you're home free.

For `M` equal to `C`, I don't think you'll have a solution for `M > 3`, because the solution for `M = 3` already depends on the fact that you can have *only* cannibals on one side and they won't be able to do anything to the missionaries no matter how many there are on one side.

The part of the solution where this applies looks something like this:

- `3 1 < 0 2`
- `1 1 > 2 2`
- `2 2 < 1 1`
- `0 2 > 3 1`

There's no way to get a similar arrangement for anything greater than three, because you can't send enough missionaries at once to balance out the rest of the cannibals.

Comment: Re *There's no way to get a similar arrangement for anything greater than three* - You're gonna need a bigger boat!

Answer (score 2):

For the case of more M than C it becomes trivial as a canibal can run the ferry after some initial setup.  It starts with 1 M and 1C in the boat with C+1 M on the original shore.  The M takes the boat back and gets another M, leaving C Ms on the original shore, The Ms get to the other side and send the C back with the boat.  The C can now ferry alternating C's and Ms without issue.  The Ms will always outnumber the number left on either shore.

If M is 2 or more higher than C, then M can actually run the boat as well since they can start with 2 Ms in the boat and keep a higher number on both shores simultaneously while also operating the boat.

Comment: You misspelled "ferry", just so you know.

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't understand :D. Are you suggesting that 3 people leave (2M + 1C) and 1M returns? _A boat can carry at most two people_.

Comment: In a more roundabout way than that, to be sure.

Comment: A missionary can't just ferry people there and back. There's a bit of subtlety there that you missed.

Comment: @JoeZ. - ok, think I accounted for that.  How does it look now for M>C.

Comment: Have a look at my answer for a slightly neater approach, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a foolproof solution:

> One missionary and one cannibal cross to the other side, 
> The cannibal gets out and the missionary comes back
>  Missionary gets out of the boat, two cannibals get in and cross
> One cannibals gets out and the other cannibal goes back
> The cannibal gets out and two missionaries get in and cross
> One missionary gets out, the other missionary stays in the boat and one cannibal gets in and goes back.
> The cannibal gets out and two missionaries get in and cross
> The two missionaries get down and the cannibal gets in the boat and goes back
> One cannibal gets in and they both cross but only one cannibal gets out
> The other cannibal in the boat goes back, collects the other cannibal, they cross and they get out.

And you should have won

Comment: This only solves the case where C=M=3. The question asks for a general solution.

Answer (score -2):

Why can't you just send one missionary and one cannibal on each trip?  Cannibals can never outnumber missionaries, but they can be equal right?

So send 1 cannibal and missionary and you're done in 3 trips.

Comment: Welcome to PSE! Especially with older puzzles, it's pretty important to review the question and existing answers before adding a new answer. In this case, your solution cannot work, because "The boat cannot cross the river by itself with no people on board."