# 3 cannibals and 3 missionaries on different side of the river

Tags: optimization, river-crossing

Three missionaries on the **left** side of a river and three cannibals on the **right** side of the river want to cross a river using a boat which can carry at most two people, The boat is on the cannibals side. Under the constraint that, for both banks, if there are missionaries present on the bank, they cannot be outnumbered by cannibals (if they were, the cannibals would eat the missionaries). The boat cannot cross the river by itself with no people on board.

Plan minimum number of trips in such a way that all the cannibals go to the left side and missionaries come to the right side without any bloodshed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strategy to solve the Missionaries and Cannibals problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/131/strategy-to-solve-the-missionaries-and-cannibals-problem)

Comment: Not a duplicate - the usual formulation (and that used in the putative duplicate) has all 6 people starting on one side and needing to cross to the other side without bloodshed. This problem has them on opposite banks and needing to trade places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It should take 5 crossings:
>
>  `MMM      <C>CC    1C crosses left`
>  `MC<MM>      CC    2M cross right`
>  `MC      <MC>MC    1M 1C cross left`
>  `CC<MM>      MC    2M cross right`
>  `CC      <C>MMM    1C crosses left`
>  `CCC<>      MMM`

Comment: on a lighter vein, does **JS1** stand for _Jamal Senjaya One_ ?

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay No, just a coincidence I guess.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually it should be doable in 4 crossings, since the question calls for the Cannibals not outnumbering the Missionaries, so I assume same amount of Cannibals and Missionaries is okay *and* embarking and disembarking is instantaneous, so no snatching of boarding missionaries while you reunite with your cannibal friends.
> MMM----------[CC]C    2C cross left
> MMCC[M]----------C    1M crosses right
> MMCC----------[C]MM   1C crosses left
> CCC[MM]----------M    2M cross right

Comment: Are there four cannibals in the middle two steps? I'm not sure how two C cross left and leave 2 behind, since there are only supposed to be 3 C. Also, aren't there 4 crossings, not 3, in your solution?

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I was struggling with the editing a bit.

Comment: I still see four cannibals in the second step? Two on either side.

Comment: I wasn't done struggling D:

Comment: Final nitpick... third step has two M on either side?

Comment: In the third step, the third cannibal arrive at missionaries side, then 3 cannibals eat two missionaries.